# event.preventDefault(); still loading

Tags: php, jquery, wamp

I pulled the template for this idea from [jquery.com](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) and included it around my form.  On submit, the form is still following the `action` and submitting to and showing **condoupdate.php**, even with the 'preventDefault' event set.  Testing on FF with `WAMP`.

```
<div style="display:block;margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;width:99%;">
<form id="condoupdate" name="condoupdate" method="post" action="condoupdate.php">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

  <tr valign="top">
    <td><img src="img/details.png" /></td>
    <td><textarea name="detail" cols="45" rows="5"><?php ECHO $extras; ?></textarea><BR /><BR /><input type="submit" class="unitBtn" name="svUnit" id="svUnit" value="Save"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" class="unitBtn" name="resetUnit" value="Reset"/><div id="result" style="margin-left:10px;display:inline;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
</form></div>

    <script>
    $("#condoupdate").submit(function(event) {

    // Stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get some values from elements on the page
    url = $("#condoupdate").attr("action");

    // Send the data using post
    var posting = $.post(url);

    // Put the results in a div
    posting.done(function(data) {
    var content = $(data).find("#content");
    $("#result").empty().append(content);

        });
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Is the event handler fired? Your posted code should work. Now silly question but what about browser cache?

Comment: Try adding "return false;" after $("#result").empty().append(content);

Comment: @Webomatik That does exactly the same thing as `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Check your Javascript console for error messages. The usual reason for something like this is a syntax error that's preventing the code from running.

Comment: In your real page, is the `<script>` block before or after the `<form>` block? If it's before, you need to put the Javascript code into `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Thank you all for the reply.  Barmar, the <script>'s are after the <form> as shown.  Console results:  A form was submitted in the windows-1252 encoding which cannot encode all Unicode characters, so user input may get corrupted. To avoid this problem, the page should be changed so that the form is submitted in the UTF-8 encoding either by changing the encoding of the page itself to UTF-8 or by specifying accept-charset=utf-8 on the form element. index.php

Comment: And this:  The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. condoupdate.php

Comment: @Barmar, it took longer to show up than the previous two, but now I get "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.", it looks like I was simply using the 1.7.x that came as part of an uploader script I was using.  Boosted it to the 1.12.2 and I have no errors -- no messages of any kind.

Comment: Your code works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/h0bmr3j5/2/ This one shows what happens if `preventDefault` doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/h0bmr3j5/1/

Comment: Am I missing something in order to get this POST to do exactly that?  My action file is php that starts like this

IF(isset($_POST['svUnit'])) { ... }

But no info seems to be being passed to the php file.